# Google Maps API installation warning

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried to add google maps API but it warns me with an error and says my project might not compile once google maps api is downloaded. I have attached a copy of image in the question if you can have a look.[warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZznB.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem between libraries version.

You either have two versions of `com.android.support-annotations`, and this other version can be inside one of your other libraries or you are using an old version of the annotations library.

Comment: i dont have this implementation in my library. is there any chance i can find it in gradle?